# Как программно сделать так, чтобы Объект UIView автоматически расширялся

Tags: ios, swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть `UIView` в ней `Label`(цена) и `image`(корзина). Если цена будет 5тизначная, то она не помещается в ширину `UIView`. Все создаю программно и накладываю друг на друга программно. Вот код:

```
func customview(vc: UIViewController, num: String){
    let v = UIView()
    v.frame.origin.x = 0.0
    v.frame.origin.y = 0.0
    v.frame.size.width = 78
    v.frame.size.height = 30
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:vc, action:Selector("boxButton:"))
    //v.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleBottomMargin, .FlexibleTopMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleRightMargin]
    v.addGestureRecognizer(touch)

    let imgBox = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "box_image_gray.png"))
    imgBox.frame.origin.x = 50.0
    imgBox.frame.origin.y = 5.0
    imgBox.frame.size.width = 20
    imgBox.frame.size.height = 20
    imgBox.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    v.addSubview(imgBox)

    let textview = UILabel()
    textview.frame.origin.x = v.frame.origin.x + 3
    textview.frame.origin.y = 0.0
    textview.frame.size.width = 50
    textview.frame.size.height = 30
    textview.text = num
    textview.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 13.0)//UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    textview.textColor = UIColor(rgba: "#F22524")
    textview.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    v.addSubview(textview)

    let logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: v)
    vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton
}
```

Как сделать чтобы `UIView` меняла ширину в зависимости от длины `UILabel`?

Смотрел на англоязычном форуме, пишут про `LayoutConstraint`, но к сожалению не разобрался как его юзать.

Comment: Можна попробувать изменить сам frame, либо если есть констреинт то сделать на нево property width и менять ево размер.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что Вы жестко задаете размер фрейма, вот и не помещается

К примеру, Вы можете набросать все в xib, а затем использовать. Или в коде прописывать ширину в зависимости от длины текста. Или программно расписать где какие constraints. Пример по Вашему случаю:

Пример на [GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/ConstraintsExampleForSO.git)

**Swift 3**:

```
func customview(vc: UIViewController, num: String){
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        //let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:vc, action:Selector("boxButton:"))
        //v.addGestureRecognizer(touch)

        let imgBox = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "box_image_gray.png"))
        imgBox.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        v.addSubview(imgBox)

        let textview = UILabel()
        textview.text = num
        textview.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 13.0)//UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
        textview.textColor = UIColor.black
        textview.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        v.addSubview(textview)

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //в Swift 2 NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(...
        v.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-5-[img(20)]-5-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["img": imgBox]))
        v.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[lbl(30)]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["lbl": textview]))
        v.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-5-[lbl(>=50)]-5-[img(20)]-5-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["img": imgBox, "lbl": textview]))
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(v.constraints)

        let logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: v)
        vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton
    }
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень изящный пример, спасибо, но к сожалению вьюха не смотря что вешается на rightBarButtonItem, при билде висит с лева.

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов можете сделать минимальный проект, где воспроизводится эта проблема?  Обновил ответ со своим примером.

Comment: Выгрузил на GitHub, вот ссылка https://github.com/muaviya/ResizeView.git

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов запустил, кнопка справа. Если у Вас слева, то очень интересный вариант получается.